# How make count comment with codeigniter,

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project. how to calculate comment by id?

example

**controler:**

```
public function comments() {

$id_alat = $this->db->where('id_alat');
$com = $this->mcrud->getComent($id_alat);
$com = $this->mcrud->getComent($id_alat);
$data = array (
                'com' => $com,
                'content' => 'instrument/instrument');
$this->load->view('layouts/wrapper', $data);
 }
```

**models:**

```
public function getComent($id_alat) {

$sql = "SELECT count (*) as num FROM WHERE tbcoment $id_alat tbcoment.id_alat = {}";
$this->db->query($sql);
}
```

**view:**

```
comments: <?php echo $com; ?>
```

Comment: **You cant defin php variable with space** `$<space>me`. should come `$me`

Comment: remove space between `$` and variable name  and `<?` and `php`.

Comment: @AK-Sonu okay there is an error creating a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code for model

**Your Model**

```
public function getComent($id_alat) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT count (*) as num FROM WHERE tbcoment.id_alat = '$id_alat'";
    $res=$this->db->query($sql)->row_object();
    return $res->num; 
}
```

Comment: i try edit your script and result its working.. thanks @Vinie

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Don't use spaces inside php tags and variables.
>
> Ex01: `$ id_alat` should come `$id_alat`
> Ex02:  `$ this-> mcrud-> getComent ($ id_alat);` should come  `$this->mcrud-> getComent($id_alat);`

**Code Example**

In controller

```
function comments () {

    $id_alat = '';//Asign data to here
    $data['com'] = $this->Model_name->getComent($id_alat);
    $data['content'] = 'instrument / instrument';
    
    $this->load->view ('layouts/wrapper', $data);
}
```

In Model

```
function getComent($id_alat) {

    $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tbcoment='$id_alat'");//cahnge table name, and argument that you want
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    return $count;
}
```

In view

```
comments: <?php echo $com; ?>
```

Comment: @Abdulia, oke there was an error made when the upload script. very nice but no way, there is a variable error message 'com' on views. $id_alat is id on controller, how to create a script

Comment: check you database part `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tbcoment='$id_alat'`, whether all arguments are correct

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this code:

```
$this->db->where('id',$id)
         ->from('table_name')
         ->count_all_results();
```

this can be used either on MVC(Model, View, Controller);

you can find this code on the user guide